# How to capture an argument with Mockito and execute real method?

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I have some integration tests that use Mockito, and they are working fine.

However, I want to verify that the input of a method that is called some time during the process I'm testing.
The thing is: I don't want to mock the method behavior, only to inspect its argument and execute the real method.
If I do something like this:

```
@MockBean
private ClassThatIsCalled classThatIsCalled;
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<TypeOfMyParameter> typeOfMyParameter;
```

I get an error because a dependency of `ClassThatIsCalled` was not found. Even If I do         `given(classThatIsCalled.callMethod(any())).willCallRealMethod();`
I'm still mocking `ClassThatIsCalled` which is not what I want to do.

Is there a way to call the productive code of `ClassThatIsCalled` (without mocking it) and simply inspect the passed argument?

TL;DR: I want to use `@Spy`/`@Captor`/similar to inspect an argument passed to a class, but without mocking the class, but calling its real method (using `.willCallRealMethod()` is not enough, since a mocked class has no dependencies injected).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`@SpyBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html):

> Annotation that can be used to apply Mockito spies to a Spring `ApplicationContext`. Can be used as a class level annotation or on fields in either `@Configuration` classes, or test classes that are `@RunWith` the SpringRunner.
>
> Spies can be applied by type or by bean name. All beans in the context of a matching type (including subclasses) will be wrapped with the spy. If no existing bean is defined a new one will be added. Dependencies that are known to the application context but are not beans (such as those registered directly) will not be found and a spied bean will be added to the context alongside the existing dependency.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class YourTest {
  @SpyBean
  private ClassThatIsCalled classThatIsCalled;
  @Captor
  private ArgumentCaptor<TypeOfMyParameter> typeOfMyParameter;

  // ...
}
```